# C# Fill textfield from looping data

Tags: c#

I want ask about data to combine string on one field and add `(,)` for each string.

this my code on C#

```
for (i = 0; i < count_; i++)
{
    accessbranch[i] = collection.GetValue("accessbranch" + i).AttemtedValue.ToString();
}
```

I want get each string and make it one a field or variable.

output I want
ex

```
banana, papaya, melon
```

add `(,)` and space

Comment: what is collection and what is accessbranch?

Comment: I needed 2 seconds to find a duplicate when i searched `"how to add comma in loop c#"` (-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Join`

```
string[] values = new string[]{"banana", "papaya", "melon"};

var result = string.Join(", ", values);
```